# Error: Cannot find control with path of arrayname => formarray inside mat table in angular8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

HTML:(Here I have a table with formArray.I want to patch Value When I select the Value from Pomaterials array.It is there bottom of the table. but When i select the item, its throwing error,cannot find control with path.I have tried formControls instead of datasource, still its giving same error. can you help me?)

```
      <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
               <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  formArrayName="receive_mat">
               <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
               <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let index = index; columns:displayedColumns;" 
                [formGroupName]="index"></tr>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="material">
                       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Material</th>
                       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                           <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" style="width: 76px">
                               <input matInput  type="text" formControlName="material" readonly/>
                           </mat-form-field>
                        </td>
                   </ng-container>

                   <ng-container matColumnDef="qty_receiving"> 
                       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Qty Receiving</th>
                       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
                       <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" style="width: 76px">
                           <input matInput  type="number" formControlName="quantityreceiving">
                       </mat-form-field>
                      </td>
                   </ng-container>
                   <ng-container matColumnDef="best_before"> 
                       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Best Before</th>
                       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
                       <mat-form-field style="width: 80px">
                           <mat-label>Best Before</mat-label>
                               <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="bestbefore" readonly/>
                               <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                               <mat-datepicker #picker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>    
                           </mat-form-field>
                       </td>
                   </ng-container>
                   <ng-container matColumnDef="delete"> 
                       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
                       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
                           Delete<mat-icon (click)="removeElement(element, index)">cancel</mat-icon>
                       </td>
                   </ng-container>
         </table>
       <!-- <button>add</button> -->
       <mat-form-field style="width:100px;margin-left:10px;">
           <mat-select  placeholder="Select Material" [(value)]="data"
            (selectionChange)="selectedItem(data)" >
               <mat-option *ngFor="let item of poMaterials" [value]="item">{{item.material_id.title}}</mat-option>
           </mat-select>
       </mat-form-field>
           <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
        </div>
```

component.ts:

```
   ngOnInit(){ 
          this.receiveForm = new FormGroup({
              'receive_mat': new FormArray([]),
          })
    this.receive_mat = this.receiveForm.get('receive_mat') as FormArray;
   this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource((this.receiveForm.get('receive_mat') as FormArray).controls);
  }
   selectedItem(item){
    console.log(item)
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource((this.receiveForm.get('receive_mat') as FormArray).controls);
    this.addItem(item)
  }
  createItem(item): FormGroup {
    console.log(item)
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      'material': new FormControl(item.material_id.title, Validators.required),
      'quantityreceiving': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'bestbefore': new FormControl(new Date()),
    })
  }
  addItem(item){
    console.log(item)
    this.receive_mat.push(this.createItem(item))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the reference of the form array and then push the item to it. Here is an example.

```
import { Component,OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit{
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  form: FormGroup;
  items: FormArray;

 constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      items: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
  }

  addItem(): void {
    this.items = this.form.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.items.push(this.createItem());   
  }

createItem(): FormGroup {
     return this.formBuilder.group({
      'material': new FormControl(item.material_id.title, Validators.required),
      'quantityreceiving': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'bestbefore': new FormControl(new Date())
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi karthick,, I have tried your solution.. this is not helping me. still I am getting same error.

Comment: @Charu - Please place your code in stackblitz.com so that it is easy to troubleshoot and fix it.

Comment: @Karthick,, Here I have provided stackblitz link.. Can you please look into it?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-form-6d6tpr?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts